# main not recognizing my function

Tags: c, string, qsort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char* lines[], int count)
{
    for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
            printf("%s", lines[i]);
    }
}
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sortutil.h"
#include "reverse.h"


int getarray(char *lines[]);
void printarray(char *lines[], int max);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* arr[100];
    int numlines = getarray(arr);
    printf("There are %d lines\n", numlines);
    printarray(arr, numlines);


    for (int i = 1; i < argc;  i++)
    {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)
            {
                    sortutil(arr);
                    printarray(arr, numlines);
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0)
            {
                    reverse(arr, numlines);
                    printarray(arr, numlines);
            }

    }
}

int getarray(char *lines[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char *text = (char *)malloc(200);
    while (fgets(text, 200, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        lines[i] = text;
        i++;
        text = (char *)malloc(200);
    }
    return i;
}

void printarray(char *lines[], int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n\n", lines[i]);
    }
}
```

when i compile the main function it is telling me that there is an undefined reference to 'reverse'. I did `#include "reverse.h"` so it shouldn't have a problem seeing the reverse function. Am I missing something

Comment: What does "reverse.h" say about reverse?  Does the error occur during compilation or linking?

Comment: @Mike linking, obviously. "Undefined reference" is a linkage issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the implementation. You defined the prototype, but the function body itself is missing. It is in a separate file, and you need to tell the linker about it. When you compile your main.cc - add the other file to the command line as well.

Comment: it did mention that the linker command failed, how would I add the other file to the command line, would I add that in the makefile?

Comment: @user3427042 generally yes. But without knowing how your makefile looks like and what linker you're using - its really hard to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: well I didn't add the sortutil.h in my command line and it still worked, I use clang if that helps btw

Comment: @user3427042 "*.h" is usually a header file, not a source file. Where is the body of the missing function?

Comment: what missing func? my reverse.c, reverse.h, main.c are all in the same directory

Comment: @user3427042 well, you know that. But does your linker know it? Does your linker know that there's a reverse.c somewhere that it should link with? Did you tell the linker that? Because that error you're getting is your linker screaming "WTF reverse? There's no reverse there!"

Comment: how do i link something? this is my main makefile command: 
main.o: main.c
        clang -c main.c -Wall -g

Comment: @user3427042 and what do you do with main.o after that?

Comment: @user3427042 I suggest you start learning this: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

Comment: after that what i do with main.o is put it in the executable: sorter: main.o sortutil.o reverse.o
        clang sortutil.o main.o -o sorter